# Creating (and accessing) an array in MIPS

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I'm trying to create an array in MIPS Assembly, and then add all the elements together.  However, when I try to assemble the following, it says

> Error in read_array line 1 position 7: ".word" directive cannot appear in text segment
>   Assemble: operation completed with errors.

Here's my assembly:

```
list: .word 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2
li $t0, 0x00000000  #initialize a loop counter to $t0
li $t4, 0x00000005  #last index of array
li $t3, 0x00000000  #this will hold our final sum
la $t1, list  #the address of list[0] is in $t1

loop: addi $t0, $t0, 0x00000001 #index++
  add $t5, $t0, $t0 #array index X2
  add $t5, $t0, $t0 #array index X2 again
  add $t6, $t5, $t1 #4x array index in $t6

  lw $t2, 0($t6)   #load list[index] into $t2
  add $t3, $t3, $t2 #$t3 = $t3 + $t2
  beq $t0, $t4, end
  j loop

end:
```

Thanks!

Comment: I am aware of some logical errors in this code, but I got my question answered.  Thanks!

Comment: That's really weird, IDK if this limitation is intentional to protect beginners from mixing data with code and having their program crash when execution falls into their data, or what.  In most assemblers, you can use `.byte` / `.word` or `db` / `dd` anywhere to emit whatever bytes you want at any position.  (e.g. to emit a non-default encoding of an instruction for some reason.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to put this line:

```
list: .word 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2
```

Into the `.data` section.  Check this [quick tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20190222083348/http://logos.cs.uic.edu/366/notes/MIPS%20Quick%20Tutorial.htm).

Comment: The 'quick tutorial' link is off.

Answer (score 6):

The error is telling you you can't put data (.word 3, 2) in the code segment. "Text segment" is an old style term meaning "code segment" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_segment

The assembler wants you to declare a data segment and put the array there.  I've never done Mips assembler, but I would expect it to be something like this

```
.data
list: .word 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2

.text
start:
li $t0, 0x00000000  #initialize a loop counter to $t0
li $t4, 0x00000005  #last index of array
li $t3, 0x00000000  #this will hold our final sum
la $t1, list  #the address o
```

Comment: It would be `.text` rather than `.code` in most assemblers I've used.

Comment: @Carl: you're probably right, especially given the error message. I'll change it.